# GREP for Processes by Directory and Kill it

Tags: grep, ps, macintosh

I'm trying to `grep` for processes that originate from the /Applications/ directory (to kill them), but my `grep` command keeps catching some false ones as well. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ ps -ef | grep -e '/Applications/' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $8}'
/Library/Application        I DON'T WANT THIS
/Library/Application        I DON'T WANT THIS
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including a whitespace in your pattern:

```
...  grep -e ' /Applications/'  ...
```

Also, `pkill` (long a standard offering in Linux) is now included in OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) and above. See http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/18/kill-process-wildcards-pkill-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning pkill. I think it will serve exactly what I need right now, which is to terminate any apps from the /Applications/ directory. I tried the following and it works. It even excludes Terminal.app on its own:
`pkill -f Applications` Haven't play around with this command much, but I will have to see if it needs to be grep-ed or anything.
I'll mark you as my accepted answer since you went above and beyond my needs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point. Edited the answer and removed the escaping on the whitespace.  OP liked the `pkill` more than the grep/whitespace tip anyhow.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that pgrep/pkill originated in Solaris, not Linux, and were added to BSDs (NetBSD first) around the same time as Linux' procps (early 2002).

Answer (score 1):

Use the anchor `^` (caret symbol), to signify the beginning of the line/field and change the command order:

```
 ps -ef | grep -v grep | awk '{print $8}' | grep "^/Applications"
```

This way, grep will run last and will only return the lines that *start* with `/Applications`.

[This](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) is also helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times I played around with the caret, but looking at your pipe arrangement, I see now where I did wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are bothering about saving CPU ticks:

```
ps -ef | awk '$8~"^/Applications/"{print $8}'
```